# method call without parenthesis doesn't forward all arguments while with parenthesis it initializes without any arguments

Tags: ruby

I know for a fact that in Ruby, parenthesis for method calls are optional. I need to understand why sometimes when a method call is made with parenthesis to initialize a base class, for instance, it doesn't forward all arguments while without parenthesis it does.

An instance is described below:

```
[1] irb(main)> class Account
[1] irb(main)*   def initialize(*args)
[1] irb(main)*     pp(args)
[1] irb(main)*   end
[1] irb(main)* end
=> :initialize
[2] irb(main)> class User < Account
[2] irb(main)*   def initialize(a, b)
[2] irb(main)*     super()
[2] irb(main)*   end
[2] irb(main)* end
=> :initialize
[3] irb(main)> class Guest < Account
[3] irb(main)*   def initialize(a, b)
[3] irb(main)*     super
[3] irb(main)*   end
[3] irb(main)* end
=> :initialize
[4] irb(main)> User.new(1, 2)
[]
[5] irb(main)> Guest.new(1, 2)
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know for a fact that in Ruby, parenthesis for method calls are optional.

That is true.

> I need to understand why sometimes when a method call is made with parenthesis to initialize a base class, for instance, it doesn't forward all arguments while without parenthesis it does.

Let's look at this again, this time I have emphasized the important bit in **bold**:

> I need to understand why sometimes when **a method call** is made with parenthesis to initialize a base class, for instance, it doesn't forward all arguments while without parenthesis it does.

Simple: it's **not a method call**. The `super` keyword is not a method, it is [a keyword](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/keywords_rdoc.html), just like `class`, `module`, `if`, `unless`, `while`, `until`, `for`, `case`, `rescue`, `yield`, `in`, `then`, `when`, `do`, `ensure`, `else`, `begin`, `do`, `end`, etc.

Since it's not a method call, there is no reason for it to follow the rules of a method call. It follows the rules of a [*`super` expression*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance).

In particular, you can find the rules for the *`super` expression* in Section 11.3.4 *The `super` expression* of [the ISO Ruby Language Specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html), specifically clauses b) 1) i)-iv) of the *Semantics* subsection:

> - b) Let *A* be an empty list. Let *B* be the top of ⟦block⟧.
>
>   - 1) If the *super-expression* is a *super-with-optional-argument*, and neither the *argument-with-parentheses* nor the *block* is present, construct a list of arguments as follows:
>
>     - i) Let *M* be the method which corresponds to the current method invocation. Let *L* be the *parameter-list* of the *method-parameter-part* of *M*. Let *S* be the set of local variable bindings in ⟦local-variable-bindings⟧ which corresponds to the current method invocation.
>     - ii) If the *mandatory-parameter-list* is present in *L*, for each *mandatory-parameter* *p*, take the following steps:
>
>       - I) Let *v* be the value of the binding with name *p* in *S*.
>       - II) Append *v* to *A*.
>     - iii) If the *optional-parameter-list* is present in *L*, for each *optional-parameter* *p*, take the following steps:
>
>       - I) Let *n* be the *optional-parameter-name* of *p*.
>       - II) Let *v* be the value of the binding with name *n* in *S*.
>       - III) Append *v* to *A*.
>     - iv) If the *array-parameter* is present in *L*:
>
>       - I) Let *n* be the *array-parameter-name* of the *array-parameter*.
>       - II) Let *v* be the value of the binding with name *n* in *S*. Append each element of *v*, in the indexing order, to *A*.

As you can see, `super` without an argument list means "pass the argument list of the original call". Whereas `super` *with* an argument list means "pass exactly this argument list". This second case is described in b) 2)-4), which I will not quote here, since it pretty much says what you expect it would say.

You can also find some information in the [ruby/spec project](https://github.com/ruby/spec/), under [`language/super_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/super_spec.rb#L227-L277):

```rb
it "without explicit arguments can accept a block but still pass the original arguments" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithBlock::B.new.a.should == 14
end

it "passes along block via reference to method expecting a reference" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithBlock::B.new.b.should == [14, 15]
end

it "passes along a block via reference to a method that yields" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithBlock::B.new.c.should == 16
end

it "without explicit arguments passes optional arguments that have a default value" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithOptional::B.new.m(1, 2).should == 14
end

it "without explicit arguments passes optional arguments that have a non-default value" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithOptional::B.new.m(1, 2, 3).should == 3
end

it "without explicit arguments passes optional arguments that have a default value but were modified" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithOptional::C.new.m(1, 2).should == 100
end

it "without explicit arguments passes optional arguments that have a non-default value but were modified" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithOptional::C.new.m(1, 2, 3).should == 100
end

it "without explicit arguments passes rest arguments" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithRest::B.new.m(1, 2, 3).should == [1, 2, 3]
end

it "without explicit arguments passes rest arguments including any modifications" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithRest::B.new.m_modified(1, 2, 3).should == [1, 14, 3]
end

it "without explicit arguments passes arguments and rest arguments" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithRestAndOthers::B.new.m(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).should == [3, 4, 5]
end

it "without explicit arguments passes arguments and rest arguments including any modifications" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithRestAndOthers::B.new.m_modified(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).should == [3, 14, 5]
end

it "without explicit arguments that are '_'" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithUnderscores::B.new.m(1, 2).should == [1, 2]
end

it "without explicit arguments that are '_' including any modifications" do
  SuperSpecs::ZSuperWithUnderscores::B.new.m_modified(1, 2).should == [14, 2]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally this is true, but `super` is special because it's not so much a method as it is [also a Ruby keyword with special properties](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance).

There's several forms at work here:

- `super` means "call the parent's method *with the same arguments this method was given*".
- `super()` means "call the parent's method with *no arguments*".
- `super a, b` and `super(a, b)` both mean "call the parent's method with *specific arguments*".

I'm not aware of any other method calls in Ruby that spontaneously send arguments that aren't specified, but `super`, by virtue of being a keyword, does look like this.

Comment: Yeah, while that is true, I know that `super` is actually a keyword and not a method, but the usage is the same nevertheless.

Comment: I'm trying to find a link to the current documentation, but [this older version](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-super) explains. It's an exception to the usual rule.

Comment: @tadman You can find the `super` keyword documented at the bottom of [this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance) chapter.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks. Updated the answer with that link.

Comment: Very helpful too, understood.